# Dirigir a url tras click con display content

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un div en el que se muestran una serie de datos recogidos desde una base. Este mismo div, lleva una función onclick donde al cliquear se redirige a una url. Luego, al hacer hover sobre este mismo anuncio, se despliega un content que cubre todo el espacio del div original y lo reemplaza por un texto denominado "contactar". Mi problema es que no logro que la función onclick tenga efecto en el momento en que este content se presenta. Es decir, si éste lo inhabilito, la función hace efecto, más si lo habilito nuevamente la función ya no tiene efecto. No se como podría solucionar este inconveniente. Adjunto mi código correspondiente.

**Código PHP donde desarrollo el div y la función onclick**

```
<?php
    $CantShow=10;
        $compag = (int)(!isset($_GET['publishpShow'])) ? 1 : $_GET['publishpShow'];
        $TotalReg = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
        $totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
        $TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr/$CantShow);
        $IncNum = (($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):0;
        $consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantShow)." , ".$CantShow);
        //$consultA = mysqli_query($conexion, $consult);
    ?>
    <div class="publishpShow">
        <?php
        while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
                $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $lista['id']);
                $usuariob = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$userid'");
                $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
        ?>
                <div class="publishContainer">
                    <div class="publish" onclick="window.location ='https://www.google.com.mx';">
                        <div class="publishCInfo">
                            <?php $date = $lista['fecha']; ?>
                            <p class="publishCDate">Publicado el <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))?> a las <?php echo date('G:i', strtotime($date))?></p> 
                            <div class="publishCZone"><p class="publishCProv">En <?php echo $lista['provincia']?></p> <p class="publishCLoc"><?php echo $lista['localidad']?></p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDisplay">
                            <div class="publishCOffer">
                                <p class="publishCQuantity"><?php echo $lista['cantidad']?></p>
                                <p class="publishCCurrency"><?php echo $lista['moneda']?></p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="publishCFee">Fee <?php echo $lista['comision']?>%</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDetails">
                            <p class="publishCOperation"><?php echo $lista['operacion']?></p>
                            <div class="publishCMethod">
                                <p class="publishCMethodAccepted">Acepta:</p><p class="publishCP2P"><?php echo $lista['p2p']?></p><p class="publishCF2F"><?php echo $lista['f2f']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

**Estilo CSS**

```
    .publishpShow {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    column-gap: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px #92929233;
    position: static;
}

   .publishpShow .publishContainer:hover::after {
    content: "CONTACTAR";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fe9416;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-top: -52%;
    color: white;
    animation: tooltips-vert .2s ease-in-out forwards;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.publishpShow .publishContainer:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Básicamente lo que preciso es que se ejecute el content y que la función onclick siga siendo válida, es decir que el content no la anule como sucede actualmente. No sé como lograr esto. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás creando el pseudo elemento *after* en un ancestro del que tiene la clase `.publish` y queda encima, por lo que no captura el clic.

En CSS cambia esta línea:

```
.publishpShow .publishContainer:hover::after {
```

Por esta otra:

```
.publishpShow .publish:hover::after
```

```css
.publishpShow {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    column-gap: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 3px #92929233;
    position: static;
}
/* El contenedor debe tener posición relativa */
.publishpShow .publish {
    position: relative;
}
/* El pseudo elemento debe pertenecer al contenedor deseado, no a su ancestro */
.publishpShow .publish:hover::after {
    content: "CONTACTAR";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fe9416;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    margin-top: -52%;
    color: white;
    animation: tooltips-vert .2s ease-in-out forwards;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.publishpShow .publishContainer:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="publishpShow">
    <div class="publishContainer">
        <div class="publish" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.com/'">
            <div class="publishCInfo">
                <p class="publishCDate">Publicado el 05-Ago/21 a las 5:00pm</p> 
                <div class="publishCZone">
                    <p class="publishCProv">En (provincia)</p>
                    <p class="publishCLoc">(Localidad)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="publishPDisplay">
            <div class="publishCOffer">
                <p class="publishCQuantity">Cantidad</p>
                <p class="publishCCurrency">Moneda</p>
            </div>
            <p class="publishCFee">Fee (Comisión)%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="publishPDetails">
            <p class="publishCOperation">Operación</p>
            <div class="publishCMethod">
                <p class="publishCMethodAccepted">Acepta:</p>
                <p class="publishCP2P">P2P</p>
                <p class="publishCF2F">F2F</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección. Muchas gracias!